# Create a new object and call a method spring configuration

Tags: java, spring

Is there a short cut way to implement the following functionality in Spring xml configuration file.

```
new MyObject().getData()
```

instead of

```
Object obj = new MyObject();
obj.getData();
```

I know how to do it in 2nd case.

```xml
<bean id="obj" class="MyObject" />

<bean id="data" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
      <property name="targetObject"><ref local="obj" /></property>
      <property name="targetMethod"><value>getData</value></property>
 </bean>
```

I am sure there must be a way to do this in a single definition. Please suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered using an anonymous bean in your `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`?

```xml
<bean id="data" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject"><bean class="MyObject" /></property>
    <property name="targetMethod"><value>getData</value></property>
</bean>
```

This is basically equivalent to what you have, except for the fact that there is no intermediate bean definition.  I am not sure whether or not the `MyObject` instance will be in your `ApplicationContext`, though, so if you need it there, you may want to look into that.

Comment: This is what I am looking for if it works. I am new to spring. I think i don't require this object to me in ApplicationContext. But, just a followup question, if it indeed is present in ApplicationContext, how can we access it?

Comment: Well, since it has no `id`, you cannot access it by name.  If you were to be able to access it, it would have to be by type autowiring, or by asking the `ApplicationContext` for the bean by its class name.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `@Autowire`.

In the classes where you need the **MyObject** bean, you could use something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

      @Autowire
      MyObject myObject;

      public void myMethodofMyClass(){
         myObject.oneMethodOfMyObject();
      }

}
```

You can find more info in the [spring reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf) (page 54).

Comment: I want to merge both xml-definitions into single, if possible. i don't want to go for Java Objects. I don't want to autowire. Is this possible?